# Compile Error in wsse authentication

Tags: php, symfony

I am using a custom Authentication Provider from the symfony book http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html and I was testing my code. If what is said in the book is correct then the wsse authentication should work correctly but I am getting a unfamiliar error:

> Compile Error: Declaration of Wsse UserToken::getCredentials() must be
>   compatible with
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface::getCredentials()

I know that I messed up somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Check that your method parameters and their types and default values (aka 'method signature') are the same as in TokenInterface.